# Different values on joining array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I use the following code to join an array into table data cells:

```
array[i] = "<td style='display:none'>"+array[i].join("</td><td>")+"</td>";
```

After using it, the first table data cell gets property, where it's not displayed, but rest of the cells get displayed. Now I also want to hide the last cell, so only the cells between the first and the last get displayed. How could I do it?

Comment: what are the contents of `array`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this really easily with CSS:

```
td:first-child, td:last-child { display: none; }
```

Things like these should be solved in CSS primarily.

Any time you use `style` you should wonder: *can I use 'class' instead?*

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work. But after searching from Google, I found that it should be td:first-child, td:last-child { display: none; } instead. Thank you for the idea anyway!